# What constitutes “against its nature” and “obviously self-destructive” for Dominate Person?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I am a DM trying to wrap my head around Dominate person.

The spell reads in part:

> Subjects resist this control, and any subject forced to take actions against its nature receives a new saving throw with a +2 bonus. Obviously self-destructive orders are not carried out.
>
> Once control is established, the range at which it can be exercised is unlimited, as long as you and the subject are on the same plane. You need not see the subject to control it.

So what I understand is that, after failing the first save, the creature gets a new save at a +2 if doing something against their nature, and that they won't do anything obviously self-destructive.

But what constitutes “against their nature” or “obviously-self destructive”? And do they get a new save for each order against their nature?

A few examples mainly to get one thinking: Which of these are “against the subject's nature”,  “obviously self-destructive”, or “neither” if the caster commands the subject to…

1. … flee from battle?
2. … attack its allies?
3. … stay still while its allies are attacked?
4. … stay still while it is attacked, bound, or locked in a cage?
5. … give its sword to an enemy?
6. … drop its sword while surrounded by enemies?
7. … remove armor while in battle?
8. … believe the caster is its most trusted ally?
9. … walk into a lava pit that is hidden by an illusion of a regular stone floor, and the subject does not know it's a lava pit?

Comment: This is hard to answer because "against the subject's nature" depends on the subject, and you didn't specify one. Do you want a general answer of what "against nature" means, or did you have a specific target in mind?

Comment: Mainly looking at a broad answer I guess... the party I run games for normally plays neutral or good aligned characters but I try and avoid any conversation regarding alignment... So... more of an in general sort of statement.

Comment: @Wyrmwood Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: I agree that "against the subject's nature" is too broad. I think "obviously self destructive," while somewhat opinion-based could be answered within the site's mandate.

Answer (score 4):

Against its nature means against its nature.  It doesn't have to do with alignment, it has to do with what sorts of things a character believes in and stands for.  I'ma go through your questions with superheroes, cause they're pretty simple and well-known so it makes it more easily accessible.  We'll go through each one with Superman, Batman, and Wonder Woman (as per Batman:The Animated Series era incarnations, if it matters). The point being that different characters that are all 'good' can have radically different natures.

1. Commands subject to flee from battle.

   Superman: this is fine.
   Batman: also fine.
   Wonder Woman: Against nature.  The character frequently quips about how amazons never retreat, etc.  Her allies occasionally have to talk her down from abandoning anything that even looks like it might be a retreat.  Because "I never run from a fight" is a core belief of the character and part of her identity, "flee from battle" would be against her nature.
2. Commands subject to attack his allies

   Superman: Only if it's nonlethal.  Attacking them's pretty much the opposite of his nature.  Sure, it happens all the time anyways, but that's because 'against nature' doesn't stop the kinds of mind control used. Heck, he won't do anything he thinks will seriously hurt his allies even when they're trying to kill him.
   Batman: Yeah, that's definitely fine.
   Wonder Woman: It's probably OK, but not against specific people, like her mom.
3. Commands subject to stay still while his allies are attacked

   Superman: Yeah, that's fine.
   Batman: Nope.  I don't know about the 'while allies are attacked' part but 'stay still in combat' is already against nature enough.
   Wonder Woman: Definitely against nature.  In the same way that running from a fight is against her nature, not charging headlong into battle is pretty much a no-go as well
4. Commands subject to stay still while he is attacked, bound, or locked in a cage

   Superman: Yeah, that's fine.  Pretty much anything that involves being super passive while everything seems like it's going bad is gonna be fine, here.
   Batman: Again on the staying still in combat is a definite no-go.
   Wonder Woman: These are probably fine, except maybe the attacked one.
5. Commands subject to give his sword to an enemy

   Superman: Yeah, that's fine.
   Batman: Definitely fine, but it's probably point-first.  Very poor choice of words.
   Wonder Woman: Same as Batman, here.
6. Commands subject to drop his sword while surrounded by enemies

   Superman: Yeah, that's fine.
   Batman: That's how he normally employs his weapons, so that would be fine.  I think 'use a weapon improperly' might be against his nature, though, so maybe not.
   Wonder Woman: Yeah, probably fine, she has other weapons.
7. Commands subject to remove armor while in battle

   Superman: That's weird, but not really 'against nature'.  It's not something that would ever happen, but it's not something there's specific dedication against, so it can work.
   Batman: Yeah, that's fine.
   Wonder Woman: Nope.  Removing bracers is specifically against the rules and stuff, and against her nature.  Doesn't work.
8. Commands subject to believe he is his most trusted ally

   Superman: Yeah, that works.
   Batman: Nope.  Trusting people who aren't him is pretty much against his nature, as is not trusting his instincts that you in fact are not said ally.
   Wonder Woman: Sure.  It's not really addressed, so it works.
9. Commands subject to walk into a lava pit, the lava pit is covered by an illusion depicting it as regular stone and the subject does not know it is a lava pit.

   This isn't against anyone's nature cause it's not against anyone's nature to walk.

Obviously self-destructive refers to the target's perceptions.  If the target thinks they'll die if they do it, it counts, regardless of if it's actually dangerous or not.  Most of your example commands could be considered obviously suicidal, depending on context and character.

The trick to the spell is you can't just assume the targets are generic members of their race or whatever; you need to know what their deepest hopes and dreams and the cores of their identity are so that you can tell if something is actually against their nature or not, even if the player never learns about any of that stuff.  It's rather a bit of work, but that's high-level D&D for you.

Comment: Being bound is probably a no-go for wonder woman as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I think about this: having an NPC cast *dominate person* on a PC is a pretty miserable experience. Players don't like being taken out of combat, and they especially don't like having the DM puppeteer their character. The wording you're looking at is a safety valve to make sure that *dominate person* doesn't last too long when used on player characters.

When one of my PCs gets hit by this spell, I turn to them and explain the rules:

- If you can argue that a given command is against your character's nature, you get a free saving throw.
- If you can argue that a given command is obviously self-destructive, you can ignore it.
- You must follow all commands to the letter, but your character is searching frantically for loopholes, trying to rules-lawyer to mitigate the damage. You should be doing that too.

As to your list: I think your items 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 are all obviously self-destructive (doing something clowny in front of enemies) unless the enemy has made a credible promise to let the character go free. For 1, 2, and 8, I would ask the player if that was against their nature, and if they said yes I would give them the save. For 9, I would still ask, but it would take quite an argument to convince me that "walk over there" would be against their nature. (Perhaps they might argue: "I'm a free spirit, I bend the knee to nobody, and I'm not going to let that wizard tell me what to do." I would accept that argument if their past role-playing had supported it.)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those really ambiguous things that is vague, because it has to be.  The range of possibilities is just too wide.  So that naturally leaves it up to the DM's discretion.  That is not to say you can't employ some pretty good gcommon sense guidelines though.

The easiest to deal with is the Self Destructive aspect.  If the dominated one will immediately die or suffer severe injury, and that danger is KNOWN to them, then the act would be construed as self destructive.  Example, walking into a pit trap filled with spikes.  Another, openly assaulting a powerful noble in their own hall when surrounded by crossbowmen.  It's pretty obvious that such actions are going to be immediately fatal to the dominated one, and should therefore be ignored.  The key here is that the one who is under the influence of the spell is not blind or ignorant of their own environment.  As such, it relies on what the subject can **perceive** or what they **know** about.  The example of the lava pit covered by an illusion would NOT be considered as self destructive because it would not necessarily be perceived by the Dominated.

"Against the Subjects Nature" is harder.  Once again, you have to get into the subjects proverbial shoes and decide what their nature actually is in order to make a call.  Here are some examples that might help.  A lawful good Paladin is not going to just up and backstab another party member.  That would be against their nature so they  would get a bonus to save there.  A wood elf is not likely to deliberately start forest fires.  A Goblin is unlikely to render first aid.  This judgement call is probably easiest to make for Lawful good characters or anyone who is a rigid kind of personality.

Chaotics are harder to make the call on because they will do various seeming contradictory things for their own goals, not someone elses.  They will give a beggar a coin (in order to fool someone else).  They might follow rigid laws because that might actually be the fastest way to accomplish something and they know it.  That's why you have to get in the head of the dominated subject in order to determine whether action x, y, or z is going to be "Against their Nature".

In the end, it's a judgement call, and the DM is the one who has to make it.